# Server 2008 R2 Virtual Disk Unallocated Space

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, raid, partition, diskmanagement, dell-openmanage

Using the OMSA tool in Windows Server 2008 R2 I have created a new RAID 5 array and virtual disk called `Vault`. This is how it appears in OMSA;

[image]

I am using 6 physical disks in the RAID.

After creating the virtual disk it appeared in the disk management area as two unallocated disk partitions;

- 1 x 2048GB
- 1 x 2607GB

[image]

However I want one large 4655GB volume, not two individual ones.

When in the disl management area for the first time I was prompted to 'initialise disk', I choose the default option which was `MBR`, although there was also `GPT` (similar to image below) - not sure if this makes any difference?

[image]

So, I right clicked on the first partition and selected `New Sample Volume`. From here I assigned a drive letter (`V`). I then thought I could extend the `V` drive with the 2607GB of unallocated space to the right, however that option is greyed out.

[image]

Have I configured something incorrectly? 
What do I need to do in order to setup the new virtual drive as one large 4655GB drive?

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The disk has to be GPT formatted to support volumes larger than 2 TB.

If you haven't put anything on the volume yet, delete it. Then right click on Disk 3 and pick "Convert to GPT", or Initialize and then pick GPT. You can then create your volume.

If you do have data on it, you can right-click Disk 3 and pick "Convert to GPT". Then you can expand the volume.